# Using RF 433 MHz Transmitter in Basement

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, rf, communication, wireless

Electronics beginner here. I am making a robot controlled by Arduino that drives around in a basement car park with obstacles ---> l[ike this](https://www.flowcreteasia.com/media/9706/case-study-images.jpg). I need to transmit and receive radio signals from it constantly at up to a range of 50m.

Currently, I have looked into using the common RF 433 MHz to do so as it seems to be a very popular option. But I am afraid that due to the special environment its effectiveness will be affected.

How can I make RF 433Mhz work with my requirements? 
Is there another RF that works better?
What about other options? Wifi? Bluetooth?

Comment: Your question is very unspecific. You could also ask “what kind of shoes fit my feet the best”? Clear answer: Every RF could fit the described purpose.

Comment: What is it about the environment that you think will affect the RF signal?  Do the remote door locks for those cars still work when underground?

Comment: You mention " transmit and receive radio signals from it constantly".  The 433Mhz ISM band has specific rules for duty cycle. You may need to use a different frequency like 900Mhz or one of the lower bands to do constant TX. Depends on your country too.

Comment: Consider looking at a digital zigbee radio.